# PndingIntentにputExtraした値が取得できない

Tags: android

AlarmManagerにPendingIntentをsetしていますが、intent.putExtraした値が、起動される側のActivityでgetIntent()するとnullになってしまいます。
PendingIntentにsetした時点では値は入っています。
何かアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。

AlarmManagerにset

```
public MyAlarmManager(Context c) {
    context = c;
    am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

public void addAlarm(AlarmItem alarmItem){
    if(isSetPendingIntent(alarmItem)) {
        //none
    }else{
        Intent intent = getMyIntent(alarmItem);
        intent.putExtra("ALARMITEM_LABEL", alarmItem.getLabel());
        Log.d("ALARMITEM_LABEL",alarmItem.getLabel());  //この時点では値が入っている
        PendingIntent mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, alarmItem.getId(),
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // 過去だったら明日にする
        if (alarmItem.getTriggerTime() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
            long oneday = 86400000;
            alarmItem.setTriggerTime(alarmItem.getTriggerTime() + oneday);
        }
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmItem.getTriggerTime(), mAlarmSender);
    }
}

private Intent getMyIntent(AlarmItem alarmItem) {
    // アラーム時に起動するアプリケーションを登録
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    Log.d("alarmItem.getId()", String.valueOf(alarmItem.getId()));
    return intent;
}
```

起動されるActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wake_up);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.wake_label);
    label.setText(intent.getStringExtra("ALARMITEM_LABEL"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ソースによると PendingIntent で起こしているのはブロードキャストレシーバなので、（おそらくそこから起動した？）アクティビティのインテントには Extra は入りません。

レシーバ内で Extra をリレーするようにしてはいかがでしょうか。